# Mysql Double Quote

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how a mysql insert ends up as the way it does.

```
insert into users (name) values ('root''');
```

yields a database entry

```
|name |
------
|root'|
```

why is this the result?

The same thing can be said about a select

```
select * from table where name='root''';
```

will grab that ressult.

Comment: The first and last one is obvious.  String must be enclosed by quote `'`.   The second quote is an escape character (ie it treats the next quote as a literal character), thus the result.

Comment: ah that makes sense. MySQL uses a quote ' as an escape value?